# Ubuntu 14.04 Installation of libdrm-dev

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management

I am trying to install `mesa-common-dev` (`sudo apt-get install mesa-common-dev`), however I get the following message:

```
mesa-common-dev: Depends: libdrm-dev(>= 2.4.52) but will not be installed.
```

So, when I tried to install `libdrm-dev`, I get the following output:

```
libdrm-dev: Depends: libdrm2 (= 2.4.52-1) but 2.4.56-1~ubuntu1 will be installed. 
        Depends: libdrm-intel1 (= 2.4.52-1) but 2.4.56-1~ubuntu1 will be installed. 
        Depends: libdrm-radeon1 (= 2.4.52-1) but 2.4.56-1~ubuntu1 will be installed. 
        Depends: libdrm-nouveau2 (= 2.4.52-1) but 2.4.56-1~ubuntu1 will be installed.
```

So, I think that this means that alternative packages are installed? However, when I again try to install `mesa-common-dev`, I get the same error as above...

Can anyone help out a newbie at Ubuntu 14.04? Thanks!

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get update` prior to installation?

Comment: Yes, I have done an update prior to the installation...

Answer (score 1):

Look at this line:

```
Depends: libdrm2 (= 2.4.52-1) but 2.4.56-1~ubuntu1 will be installed.
```

It says the `libdrm-dev` to be installed is `2.4.52-1` and requires its dependencies all versioned in `2.4.52-1`. But your apt-get only has `2.4.56-1~ubuntu1` available.

Thus, you may try to 'upgrade' the version of `libdrm-dev`, that is version `2.4.56-1~ubuntu1`, as same as its newer dependencies in your case. Now if you google again with keywords `libdrm-dev 2.4.56-1~ubuntu1`, and within a few clicks, the download link may pop up and `wget` it like so:

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/192227986/libdrm-dev_2.4.56-1~ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Then, make sure the dependencies are installed:

```
sudo apt-get install libdrm2 libdrm-intel1 libdrm-radeon1 libdrm-nouveau2
```

Now install the freshly downloaded libdrm-dev:

```
sudo dpkg -i libdrm-dev_2.4.56-1~ubuntu1_amd64.deb
rm libdrm-dev_2.4.56-1~ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Hope everything goes smoothly!

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue when attempting to install the [Mutate](https://github.com/qdore/Mutate) launcher on Ubuntu 15.04.  The solution that worked for me was to add the [xorg-edgers PPA](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/xorg-edgers?dist=vivid):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install <whatever you were trying to install>
```

I found that by adding this PPA, these dependencies became resolvable when I tried to install the launcher.