# Can't install mesa-common-dev

Tags: opengl, mesa

I can't install this package, it gives me an error, this is the output from terminal:

```
➜  ~  sudo apt-get install mesa-common-dev        
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
mesa-common-dev : Depends: libdrm-dev (>= 2.4.52) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried `apt-get -f install` but nothing happend. Please Help, I need this for creating OpenGL apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what tells you `apt-cache policy libdrm-dev`?

You must look these posts:

- [Ubuntu 14.04 Installation of libdrm-dev](https://askubuntu.com/questions/581242/ubuntu-14-04-installation-of-libdrm-dev)
- [Unmet dependencies for libgl1-mesa-dev while initializing build environment for android](https://askubuntu.com/questions/422021/unmet-dependencies-for-libgl1-mesa-dev-while-initializing-build-environment-for)

I guess you have some conflicting package repositories/ppa. Or you have to built it manually, but only if you are sure you need a package version not provided by public repositories)

Always look at: ***[How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)***
Or try to install other version of the conflicting packages: ***[How to install specific Ubuntu packages, with exact version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92019/how-to-install-specific-ubuntu-packages-with-exact-version)***